# Cannont convert char to int?

Tags: c++, string, vector, stringstream

I'm unable to convert a `char` to an `int` and I have no idea why.

I simply want to convert some data that I parse from a CSV from `string` to `int` and the compiler won't let me.

I get this error:

> invalid cast from type '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > >::value_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to type 'int'

Note I have also tried:

```
static_cast<int>(data[2]);
```

and even

```
'a' - data[2];
```

Am I missing something? I feel like I've done this a million times.

```
time_t startDate;
string ID;
int beds;
int numDays;
string token;
vector<string> data;

for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){ // run through the rest of the file
    getline(customers, line);
    stringstream s(line); // to parse the csv

    while(getline(s,token, ',')){
        data.push_back(token);
    }

    startDate = changeToInt(data[0]);
    ID = data[1];
    ---> beds = (int)data[2];
    ---> numDays = (int)data[3];
```

Answer (score 5):

`data` is a `vector` of strings.

Therefore `data[0]` is a single `string`.

There is no clear conversion from `"Hello World"` (a `string`) to an `int`.

The error message is correct.

If you're confident the string is *int-like* (such as `"1234"`), then I recommend `std::stoi()`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to parse the `string` and convert it to an `int` using a function like `std::stoi()`.  You cannot use a cast to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to convert `string` to `int`, not `char` to `int`,
to convert `string` to `int`, you can use `std::stringstream;`

If value converted is out of range for `int` data type, `stringstream` returns `INT_MIN` or `INT_MAX`.

```
std::stringstream ss("");

ss << data[1];

ss >> ID;
```